# Google Geofence API only with GPS?

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, geofencing, android-geofence

I tought that the Google Geofence API wouuld also work without GPS signals. For instance when I am underground in a metro station and do NOT receive any GPS signals, but I have 3G/4G internet connection or receive some WiFi signals. So that the 4G internet connection gateway would provide some location information?

I tested a sample app of mine, and underground geofences were not recognized.

**So does the Google Geofence API work with GPS only?**